# What does »fiß, biste patzt» mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Walter Kempowski's novel *Uns geht's ja noch gold* I came upon the phrase »Fiß biste patzt«.  Context (emphasis mine):

> Oder Gemüsepaste.  **Fiß biste patzt**.  Die frequentierte man nicht so gern.

[Google books search](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=Fi%C3%9F+biste+patzt) yields a few more results.  It appears most if not all are from Kempowski:

> "Nein, es gab Nudelauflauf mit Kartoffelings, wie ihn mein Vater so gerne aß. »Malsoweit«, hieß es, und: »**Fiß, biste patzt**.«

(from *Tadellöser und Wolff*, Walter Kempowski)

A [non-Kempowski usage comes from this forum post](https://www.rund-ums-baby.de/forenarchiv/schwanger/2012-09/Wie-bekomm-ich-meine-schokosucht-in-griff_2545.htm):

> Ohja... Schoki :-) Lecker! Iss man ruhig - meine Oma sagte früher immer zu mit [sic] "fiss biste patzt"

Or the title of [this weblog](https://www.ankegroener.de/blog/?p=1856).  However, it's possible that Kempowski invented this and that both are quoting Kemposki.

What does »fiß, biste patzt» mean?  How do I parse it?  I think it's in a northern German dialect, possible Rostock dialect.  It's clearly related to food, and perhaps not particularly positive.

Wiktionary has no entry for [fiß](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fi%C3%9F) or [fiss](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiss).  It lists [biste](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/biste) as northern German dialect for *bist du*, and lists two meanings for [patzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/patzen); firstly *einen nicht so gravierenden Fehler (Patzer) begehen*; the second meaning is Bavarian which would an unlikely fit, this being in Rostock.  Those meanings do not make sense to me in the context of commenting on food.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is „Friss biste platzt!“.

Comment: I'd buy (at least) two _`r`_'s.

Comment: "patzen" means "to fail". "platzen" means "to burst"

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Imagine your mouth is really full. Then try to say: "Friss, biste platzt!" (Eat until you burst.)

Comment: @Olafant Ahaa, I think I get it now — *friss* being the imperative of *fressen*, and *biste* is *bis du*

Comment: @gerrit Yes. Exactly. ;)

Comment: it's just a typo

Comment: @äüö In two different books in multiple different locations the identical typo?  Unlikely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know the original work, however, I would propose another explanation for the peculiar spelling of the phrase

> Fiss biste patzt!  <--[derived from]-- Friss bis du platzt!

That's not at all a dialectal pronunciation. It is, quite conceivably, the pronunciation that would happen if you stuffed your mouth with food and then tried to utter that sentence, as with a full mouth you have a hard time pronouncing r or l.

As good writers don't write things just so but do it with a reason, I am sure this is a deliberate mise-en-scène of a voracious person speaking.

You could go to the extreme with this, i.e. imagining a person with a totally fully stuffed mouth. This person would then probably be heared saying something like:

> Fiff biffe papf!

But I suppose Kempowski found this too much, and also a bit too difficult to trace back to the intendend meaning.

Comment: Eine nette Theorie, aber ohne Textbelege irgendwie nicht mehr. Kempowskis "Tadellöser & Wolff. Ein bürgerlicher Roman" oder "Uns geht's ja noch gold" (in denen das Zitat u.a. vorkommt) haben einige "interessante" Wörter, z.B. _immerhinque_, _hervors-prützt_ oder Steigerungsformen _Tadellos-Tadellöser-Tadellöser & Wolff_. Sprüche die man innerhalb von Familien/Freunden heute als "Insider" bezeichnen könnte, bzw. einen familiären Sprachjargon. Man schaue nur auf den Titel des 2. Buchs. Daher denke ich das Zitat ist auch eher ein Kalauer a la _zum Bleistift_ als ein phonetischer Vergleich.

Comment: Wie um alles in der Welt soll das denn ein Kalauer sein?

Comment: @infinitezero  In der Tat, als Kalauer könnte es nur gelten, wenn man *jegliches* Sprach- und Wortspiel damit bezeichnete. - Den Vergleich mit dem Lautverdrehspiel *zum Bleistift* (plus 5000 andere Beispiele, zuletzt in "Quer" im Bayerischen Rundfunk: *3 Millionen Irre könnten nicht wählen*) finde ich auch nicht haltbar. Das eine ist ein Verdrehen von Lautfolgen ohne tieferen Sinn (zum Beispiel zum Bleistift), das andere ist eine lautmalerische Darstellung des im Satz Gemeinten (*Fiff bifte papft*).

Comment: @mtwde  Das eine schließt das andere nicht aus. Der Satz "Fiss biste patzt" kann im Hause Kempowski ein *Insider-Witz* gewesen sein. Unbeschadet dessen ist die Herleitung aus der Lautmalerei eine plausible Erklärung seiner Entstehung (und dann literarischen Verwendung). Ich kann natürlich nicht *beweisen* dass es so ist. Textbelege? Hä? ... Muss mal meine Briefeschachtel durchwühlen, ob da noch die alten Briefe von Kempowski sind...

Comment: It's necessary to gauge the theories certainty; A usual heuristic would be earlier textual evidence; lacking which, it's open for interpretation, in the hope to possibly reaffirm the theory, or falsify it. Now, I find the allusion to "fressen" a bit harsh, and the phono-culinary explanation a little lacking, though it would be strong enough to explain also "p[l]atzen". …

Comment: … I find an isolated "**fiß**" more appealing after having looked into "breakfast" to compare "break" with "pre" > Ger "früh" (cp *break o'dawn*), Ir. "ar" (cp *early, ere*, Ger *eh* ~ *ehe*), as well as "fast" with regional "piece" (bread, meal), Ger "bissen" (etc. other historic roots), as well as its usual interpretation as "breaking the fast", e.g. perhaps a feast after communion mass, cp distantly Arab. *sabah* "morning", Sem. *sabbath* "holy fasting time"; Now I would compare *Vesper* for analogy, and ... Oh note *Ves-*, isn't that interesting? Also cp the colocation *essen fassen*.

Comment: Klar, es ist eine mögliche Herleitung, aber ebenso möglich wäre ein Großvater ohne Zähne, ein Vater der sich für witzig hält, ein [wütendes Kind](https://www.beautyboard.de/showthread.php/245357-Kindermund/page3#post_3221924) oder einfach doch nur ne [kindliche Platt-Variante](http://www.sprachlog.de/2008/04/12/all-you-can-eat/#comment-2486). Und vielleicht gibt das Buch eine davon her und macht aus der (wie gesagt möglichen) Theorie mehr. Schließlich hat es den Ausdruck verbreitet und vielleicht sogar erfunden.

Answer (score 6):

Scheint ein Dialekt oder Jargon zu sein.

> Friss bis Du platzt.

Also `iss wie ein Tier, bis Du platzt`.

`Friss` schrieb man bis vor ca. 20 Jahren noch `Friß`.

Comment: -1 for consequently answering in the wrong language

Comment: Wird langsam langweilig.

Comment: Dann sorge doch einfach für eine entsprechende Übersetzung?

Comment: Ich bin nicht der Meinung, dass Deutsch eine falsche Sprache ist - das weißt Du aber. Du willst nicht überzeugen, sondern Dich nur durchsetzen. Vielleicht kommst Du damit ja in Deinem sonstigen Umfeld gut an - bei mir nicht so.

Comment: Wenn die Eingangssprache Englisch ist, ist Deutsch die falsche Sprache. Ist die Eingangssprache Deutsch, ist Deutsch die richtige Sprache. Die Begründung, warum das sinnvoll ist, wurde mehrfach gegeben. Wenn man das nicht verstehen **will**, dann muss man mit dem -1 leben.

Comment: Seit wann legst Du fest, was eine hinreichend sinnvolle Begründung ist und was nicht? Genauso gut kann ich fragen, ob Du nicht lesen kannst, oder wieso Du meine Ansicht zum Thema noch nicht zur Kenntnis genommen hast oder welche Schwierigkeiten psychischer Art Dich daran hindern, diese zu dulden.

Comment: Wir sollten dieses niveauvolle Gespräch im Chat austragen

Comment: @infinitezero  Auf Deutsch oder auf Englisch?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100659/diskussion-zwischen-user-unknown-und-infinitezero